# How to properly use Jinja2 count/length without errors?

Tags: python, jinja2, bottle

I've got this in my template:

```
<h2>
    Users ({{ users|length }})
</h2>
```

And I've also got a loop showing rows of users:

```
    {% for user in users %}    
    <tr>
        <td>
            {{ user.email }}
            etc...
        </td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

I can't see what I'm doing wrong. The users table works great. But when I add the h2 with the length filter, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/sean/Projects/appcash.me/_git/www/bottle.py", line 856, in _handle
    return route.call(**args)
  File "/Users/sean/Projects/appcash.me/_git/www/bottle.py", line 1721, in wrapper
    rv = callback(*a, **ka)
  File "/Users/sean/Projects/appcash.me/_git/www/views/admin.py", line 27, in custom_admin_page
    return template('admin/users.html', users=users)
  File "/Users/sean/Projects/appcash.me/_git/www/bottle.py", line 3487, in template
    return TEMPLATES[tplid].render(kwargs)
  File "/Users/sean/Projects/appcash.me/_git/www/datafly/core.py", line 184, in render
    return self.tpl.render(**_defaults)
  File "/Users/sean/Projects/appcash.me/_git/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 969, in render
    return self.environment.handle_exception(exc_info, True)
  File "/Users/sean/Projects/appcash.me/_git/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/environment.py", line 742, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "<template>", line 3, in top-level template code
  File "<template>", line 57, in top-level template code
  File "<template>", line 8, in block "content"
TypeError: object of type 'Cursor' has no len()
```

Comment: Could you clarify how you 'add the h2 with the length filter'?

Answer (score 5):

You can try this:

```
{{ users.count() }}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `users` variable seems to be of type `Cursor` (which has no length).

Perhaps you meant to do `rows = users.fetchall()` in your python (not template) code?  Then `len(rows)` will work, as will `rows|length` in your template.